# docker stack - commit changes of docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I wanted to change the placement (manager/worker) of several containers in my docker stack deployment (swarm). Now im asking myself how i can commit the changes of my docker-compose.yml file to the deployed stack as I changed/extended the following:

```
deploy:
      ...
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
```

I already checked the docker docs on this but I found nothing according to this so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing your docker-compose.yml, you can run another `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml ...` to the same stack name and docker will update the new target state. And with that new target state, swarm mode will perform the changes to the services.